# Getting a syntax error for a SQL query with a call to function

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error

I have a simple function declared and called into a query. I am getting an error at in my SQL query near dosagecount

```
CREATE FUNCTION dosagecount 
    (@dosage DECIMAL(2, 2),  
     @frequency INT,
     @frequencyinterval INT)
RETURNS DECIMAL(2,2) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @dosePerDay DECIMAL(2,2);

    SET @dosePerDay = @dosage * @frequency / @frequencyinterval;
    RETURN @dosePerDay
END;


DECLARE @dosagecount DECIMAL(2,2);

SELECT 
    caseNumber, patientAge, gender,   
    @dosagecount(dosage, frequency, frequencyinterval) 
AS dosePerDay  
FROM 
    patientView;
```

Comment: We can’t really help all that much without knowing what RDBMS you’re working with. Please tag it. [ask]

Comment: Please provide the full text of the error *exactly* as it’s being presented to you. Error messages contain extremely pertinent information that is essential to resolving the exact issue you’re encountering

Comment: In addition, how about to rename function to getDosagecount? Because variable name and function name is same.

Comment: So what is `DECIMANL` supposed to be? Not only should a tag be added for the DB that you have (as the information hovering the `sql` tag says to do), what is the ACTUAL error message? (add the ENTIRE error to the question, do not paraphrase the error)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the valuable feedback.

RDBMS I'm using is SQL Server.

I finally resolved the error by making changes to the function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dosagecount 
    (@dosage DECIMAL(9, 2),
     @frequency INT, 
     @frequencyinterval INT)
RETURNS DECIMAL(9, 2) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @dosePerDay DECIMAL(2, 2);

    SET @dosePerDay = @dosage * @frequency / @frequencyinterval;
    RETURN @dosePerDay
END;



DECLARE @dosagecount DECIMAL(9,2);

SELECT 
    caseNumber, patientAge, gender,     
    [dbo].dosagecount(dosage, frequency, frequencyinterval) AS dosePerDay  
FROM 
    patientView;
```

Please do note the usage of `[dbo].` to call the function which resolved the syntax error.

I also got an arithmetic error which was resolved by increasing the size of the decimal to 9,2

Comment: Do you **really** have `DECIMAL(2,2)` as your datatype for `@dosePerDay` in the function?? This means: **2** digits in total, **2** of which after the decimal point - so basically **no digits** before the decimal point... is that **really** what you wanted??

Comment: It could also avoid an error for dividing by zero. `RETURN @dosage * @frequency / NULLIF(@frequencyinterval, 0)`